# Why is the `using System` directive not necessary here? C# | Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, namespaces, using, using-directives

The [C# doc on the `using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) says

> The `using` directive allows you to use types defined in a namespace without specifying the fully qualified namespace of that type.

I understood this to mean that if you want to use `System.Console`, you have two options -- either

1. include a `using System` directive in your code which allows you to refer to `System.Console` simply as `Console`; or,
2. fully-qualify `System.Console` -- i.e. refer to `System.Console` as `System.Console`.

Yet, I have the following C# code in Visual Studio Code and it works even though I didn't include a `using System` directive and even though I refer to `System.Console` as just `Console`

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
List<String> names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Eve"];
foreach (String name in names) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
}
```

- `Console` lives in the `System` namespace
- `List` lives in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace

I am neither fully-qualifying `System.Console` nor did I include a `using System` directive.
Similarly for `List`.
Yet, the code runs fine and prints the following the console:

```
Hello World!
Hello Alice!
Hello Bob!
Hello Eve!
```

Comment: See the duplicate and then check .csproj for `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>`.

Comment: @user246821 I would argue that OP is concerned about not understanding how it works.

Comment: @GuruStron: Interestingly enough the article referenced (via URL) in the post above contains a blue box that mentions _top level statements_ with a link to [C# console app template generates top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

Comment: Thanks @Guru and @user246821. The table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives) lists the "implicit using directives" used by different SDKs. And I did check my `.csproj` - I'm using `"Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` which includes `System` and `System.Collections.Generic` in its implicit using directives. My`.csproj` also has the `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` line. So everything checks out.

Comment: @joseville was glad to help! Feel free to upvote the duplicate if you found it useful.